# Which actual class/interval boundary is correct?

Tags: statistics

Calculate the mean of the following data set where x is the value of the tips paid in a restaurant, rounded down to the nearest pound:

[image]

There are 3 ways in which I can write the ACB for the 1st group:

1. $0.01 \le x \le 5.99\\$
2. $ 0 \le x < 6 \\$
3. $ 0.01 \le x < 6 \\$

In the textbook the mean is £15.30 (no, it isn't rounded down/truncated), but I end up with £15.31 for every form I try, so there is no way for me to know which one is correct...

Comment: If you use $0 \le x \le 5.99$ etc. and then the midpoints (such as $2.995$) then you get an average about $15.3064$ which rounds down to $15.30$

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to round down the mean (no other mean in the answer section is rounded down). Maybe the question is worded badly?

Comment: The formula is to approximate the sample mean as $\bar X = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^k f_im_i,$ where $n = \sum_{i=1}^k f_i$ is sample size, $f_i$ is frequency, $m_i$ is midpoint (of $i$th interval), and $k$ is number of intervals. In your example, it is not exactly clear how to find $m_i.$ I seem to have make the same choice as @Henry because I get the same answer. // Nothing would surprise me about the answer book. Typically, they are hastily done and not checked for accuracy. Publishers seem to have little motivation to be sure they are correct.